# How can I optimize my LSTM model for time series prediction with multiple input features and 6 output series?

Tags: time-series, lstm

i am currenlty working on Time series prediction problem using the LSTM model.

`model = Sequential()`
`model.add(LSTM(28, dropout=0.0, input_shape=(time_step, 12)))`
`model.add(Dense(6))`
`model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')`
`history = model.fit(array_data_train_all, array_y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=14, verbose=2)`

the model is built to be fed by 12 different features to predict 6 output future  series.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can try out these following methods.

i) Try different values for the LSTM memory cell unit with respect to the complexity of the data.

ii) Also use different values for dropout to prevent overfitting.

iii) You can try using different optimizers other than 'adam' to see whether it improves accuracy or not.

iv) Also increase no.of epochs to check whether the accuracy improves or not.

v) Consider adding more LSTM layers with different number of neurons. If the data is more complex, it potentially improves the accuracy.

vi) Try different activation functions for the dense layer.